# Output Redirect Headers on Admin Dashboard Page

Tags: hooks, wp-redirect, oauth

**Question:**
Is there a way to output headers with either `wp_redirect() or header()` when a user is requesting an admin dashboard page with additional query parameters?

ex: https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=example_page+auth_code=1234xyz+state=abcdef1234

When I try calling either function above in my PHP script which displays the admin page, (hooked into `add_submenu_page`) nothing is done, and the page simply terminates

**Reason:**
I am trying to implement OAuth 2.0 with Intuit Quickbooks Online and need to refresh the redirect link sent back from Intuit Quickbooks. I need to strip the `$_GET` parameters and placing them in `$_POST` so that they are not publicly accessible. Currently I am echoing JavaScript to facilitate the redirect `<script>window.href.location="https://example.com"</script>`. This works, but I would like to not have to echo JavaScript to achieve this.

**Code:**

```
function submenu_hook_function(){
        require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "quickbooks-sync.php");
}

//...inside quickbooks-sync.php...
if (isset($_GET['code'])  && isset($_GET['state'])){

    $self_url = site_url( '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=quickbooks_sync', 'https' );

    if (headers_sent()) {
        die("<script>window.location.href='$self_url'</script>");
    } else {
        header('Location: ' . $self_url);
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using [this hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/load-page_hook/) that you can use to perform the redirect only when requesting a specific menu page - `$hook = add_submenu_page( ... ); add_action( "load-$hook", 'your_function' );`. Btw, isn't it possible to let Intuit send the GET params as POST?

Comment: Thanks, I will try that hook and see! As far as the developer docs go, I do not see an option to send the GET params as POST: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0#step-4-handle-the-oauth-2-0-server-response

Comment: Alright then, hopefully the hook works for you - but it should work. Alternatively, in your redirect URL, you could add custom/unique parameter and use the `init`, `admin_init` etc. hook (depending on what WordPress data you need to check for upon receiving the Intuit's response) to check for the params and redirect if applicable.